# GDB: Attempt to use a type name as an expression

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I am facing an ambiguity with my variable names and gdb reserved keywords. I have few variables named as 'param', 'header'. Now I cannot change the variable names as it is a very big project. I am unable to print the contents of these variables using print command in gdb as I am getting below error.

```
(gdb) print param
Attempt to use a type name as an expression

(gdb) print header
Attempt to use a type name as an expression
```

Is there any option available in gdb to resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: `(gdb) p param` prints the correct value `$1 = 1` in a test program I wrote. Did you compile the program with the debug flag (`-g`)?

Comment: Use quotes. Does `print 'param'` work? Source: [this blog](https://leifproblems.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/using-source-variable-names-in-gdb-that-are-also-reserved-words/)

Comment: *"Now I cannot change the variable names as it is a very big project"* - That should be possible to do quite easily in a good IDE

Comment: @klutt Even though that's true, changing the names of variables in a program just to debug it is not a scalable solution.

Comment: Works fine here are you sure this is coming from gdb.  I even created a type named param in my C++ program.  Works still fine.  Just a wild guess.  What version of gdb are you using? I am using `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git` (`gdb --version`).

Comment: What is the output of `ptype param` and `show language` ?

Comment: What is the type of these variables?

Comment: (gdb) ptype param  type = struct param { krb5_deltat delta; char *p;}

Comment: (gdb) show language    The current language is  "auto; currently c++"

Comment: These variables are complex objects of user defined classes

Comment: Ok, can you show us the line of source code where you declare the variable `param`? There might be some way to specify, to gdb, the variable rather than the struct tag.